# USBee AX PRO input level

Tags: logic-analyzer

I have a USBee AX Pro logic analyser

[image]

with 8 digital inputs accepting 0 to 5v.

I also have a bpt perla intercom.

It's working with a 2 wires bus (only 2 wires between outdoor and indoor panels) used for power and voice/command.
So on the indoor device, only 2 connectors.

On idle there is a 18v voltage.

Now i'd like to use my logic analyser to find the 'pattern' sent when I press the unlock door button.  But in that state it is not possible because the usbee works with 5v and the intercom with 18v.

What can I do for having it working ?  A resistance, a voltage regulator, ... ?

Answer (score 0):

R1 and R2 form a voltage divider. If V1 is 18V, OUTPUT will be 5.07V (note that resistor tolerances will be way less precise than the 0.07V exceeding 5V). If you use 10k for R1, OUTPUT will be 5.7V, 15k will give 4.3V, etc..

For other values you can search for voltage divider calculators online or use the following formula:

[image]

D1 and D2 are voltage clamp diodes.

D1 makes: Output <= 5V + Vdrop (typically 5.7V)

D2 makes: Output >= 0V - Vdrop (typically -0.7V)

The voltage clamps and voltage divider are somewhat redundant (you could just use a series resistor with clamp diodes).

You might want to add a further series resistor to protect your logic analyzer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcfCfQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>